# Connect to asterisk via Zoiper installed on Android device

Tags: android, asterisk

I've just installed Asterisk following the official documentation.
Now I am trying to set a new account on Zoiper and connecting it to asterisk.
I provide the following information :

```
Account name : 6001
Host : 192.168.1.124 (my wifi ip address)
Username : 6001 as in the documentation
Password : 123456
```

I've also installed Zoiper on my machine, and provided 127.0.0.1 as a host, still, nothing.

```
Asterisk 13,
Xubuntu 14.04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto /etc/asterisk/ make a backup of sip.conf(sudo mv /etc/asterisk/sip.conf /etc/asterisk/sip.conf.bak), extensions.conf(sudo mv /etc/asterisk/extensions.conf /etc/asterisk/extensions.conf.bak). Create a new sip.conf file using your favourite editor and paste the following into it:

```
[general]
context=internal
allowguest=no
allowoverlap=no
bindport=5060
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
srvlookup=no
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
alwaysauthreject=yes
canreinvite=no
nat=yes
session-timers=refuse
localnet=192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0

[6001]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret= 123456
context=internal
```

then save it. create a new extensions.conf file using your favourite editor and paste the following into it:

```
[internal]
exten => 6001,1,Answer()
exten => 6001,2,Dial(SIP/6001,60)
exten => 6001,3,Playback(vm-nobodyavail)
exten => 6001,4,Hangup()
```

save it.
open zoiper select setting

1.create a new account

1. select sip
2. in user field type 6001
3. in Password field type your secret (123456)
4. in domain field type your asterisk server ip

keep other fields unfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved :

- sip channel wasn't installed.
- then the firewall was blocking communications.

Thank you all.